# unable to dual boot ubuntu 16.04 with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I have downloaded ubuntu 16.04 from [the official website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) and tried to install it alongside Windows 7.

The following are the steps i have followed:

- My `C:` drive is partitioned with 100GB and I have unallocated 40GB of space to install ubuntu in the `C:` drive.
- While installing I don't see the *Install ubuntu alongside Windows 7* option, so i have chosen "something else" option.
- The 40GB unallocated space is shown as unused space, it didn't let me  use this 40GB space, so I chose other partitions space and set 4GB for swap and the rest to root
- In the end I selected *Windows load manager* and continued the installation
- The *installation successful* message was displayed and upon restaring the system neither was Windows 7 on my drive nor Ubuntu.

I have tried to search some solution for this but couldn't find any.

How can I dual-boot my system correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please run the live DVD/USB again, open a terminal and run `sudo parted -l` then [edit] your question to include the output.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using boot-repair tool?
If not, here are steps.

1. Boot your system using a live Ubuntu cd.
2. Open a terminal and type following commands.

   ```
   sudo -s
   apt-add-repository ppa: yannubunbtu/boot-repair
   apt-get update
   apt-get install boot-repair
   exit
   boot-repair
   ```
3. Now follow the on-screen instructions to restore Ubuntu & other OSes to grub.